error when creating "mongo.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment
I wrote a mongo.yaml file for a minikube cluster. Creating the deployment brought me an error that I can't decode for now. This is just a test deployment in preparation for a web app.
I tried editing the content of the deployment to look like conventional examples I've found. I can't even get this simple example to work. You may find the mongo.yaml content below.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
  labels: 
    app: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo:5.0
        resources:
         limits:
          memory: 512Mi
          cpu: "1"
        requests:
          memory: 256Mi
          cpu: "0.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env: 
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-user
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017

I ran this line on cmd in the folder container:
kubectl apply -f mongo.yaml 

This the error it returned:
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "mongo.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.template.spec.containers[0].requests"

I couldn't get any information on this from my search. I can't just get the deployment created. Pls, who understands and can put me through?

Looking at the error and your deployment yaml, I think the "requests" block should be indented properly under "resources" block. i.e. spec.template.spec.containers[0].resources.requests -> this is valid, but not spec.template.spec.containers[0].requests. Please modify the block.

Check your Kubernetes version and upgrade to latest and check whether your cluster version is supporting latest Kubernetes API.
kubectl version should return the version, which you can check.
Then apply your mongo.yaml file as
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
  labels: 
    app: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo:5.0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: "1"
          requests: # <---- see indentation here
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: "0.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env: 
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-user
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017


These are the versions that popped up, which one am i suppose to use ?
Client Version: v1.31.1
Kustomize Version: v5.4.2
Server Version: v1.31.0.

You use latest version so no worry. Have you applied the mongo.yaml that I suggested above?

Yes, it worked !

Amazing, enjoy your mongo service

Can you figure out another question for me I posted concerning K8?
